# Determine all possible $\phi$

Tags: group-theory

Let $\phi: S_6 \to \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ be a homomorphism. Explain why $[S_6,S_6]$, the commutator subgroup of $S_6$, is a subset of ker($\phi$) and after that determine all possible $\phi$.

---

For the first part I picked a random element in the commutator subgroup $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$. From the definition of homomorphisms it follows that:

$\phi(a^{-1}b^{-1}ab)=\phi(a^{-1})\phi(b^{-1})\phi(a)\phi(b)$

Since $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian we can rearrange the above as follows:

$\phi(a^{-1})\phi(a)\phi(b)\phi(b^{-1})=\phi(a^{-1}abb^{-1})=\phi(1_G)=1_H$

That proves the inclusion.

When it comes to the second part I get totally stuck. I'm not even sure I fully understand the question. How do I do this?

Comment: I'd start by finding $[S_6,S_6]$.

Comment: @carmichael561: good luck :)

Answer (score 4):

**1)** Because $$S_6/\ker(\varphi)\cong \text{Rang}(\varphi)\leq \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z,$$
and thus $S_6/\ker(\varphi)$ is abelian. Therefore $[S_6,S_6]\leq \ker(\varphi)$.

Notice that $[G,G]$ is the smallest group s.t. $G/H$ is abelian. Therefore, $G/H$ is abelian if and only if $[G,G]$ is a subgroup of $H$.

**2)** By the fondamental theorem of quotient group, $$\hat \varphi:S_6/\ker(\varphi)\longrightarrow \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$$ 
is well defined and the unique homomorphism s.t. $$\hat \varphi(x\ker\varphi)=\varphi(x).$$

Since $S_6/\ker(\varphi)=\left<(123456)\ker\varphi\right>$ (why ?), you'll get that $\hat\varphi$ is only depending on $\hat\varphi((123456)\ker\varphi)$. Now, you finally get the result (and thus that $\varphi$ only depending on $\varphi((123456))$). At the end, you should find 2 homomorphism that are $$\varphi_1:(123456)\longmapsto 1$$
and
$$\varphi_2:(123456)\longmapsto 5.$$

Moreover, you have the trivial homomorphism (i.e. that send everything to $0$), and thus, you have 3 homomorphisms.

Comment: What an elegant proof. Thanks! Is my approach incorrect or would it suffice as well?

Comment: @Snoop: Your proof is totally correct, and there is nothing to add :-)

Comment: @Surb You are generating $S_3$ not $S_6$. One should take for example $(12),(23456)$ as generators.

Comment: @Snoop: Notice that the proof for 2) is a little bit more complicated than the beginning.

Comment: We have $(12345) \in S_6$ and $|(12345)|=5$, but there is no element in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ with order $5$, so how can $|\phi((12345))|=5$?

Comment: @Snoop: I completed my proof. Notice that $(12345)\in \ker(\varphi)$. I don't know if you can imagine, but the kernel of $\varphi$ contain $120$ elements.